# Will SSDTBI for Visual Studio 2013 work with SQL Server 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

Currently I am creating SSIS packages for SQL server 2012 using Visual Studio 2012 and the SSDTBI for VS2012. This works well (but there are a lot of bugs in the SSIS package designer).

Microsoft have just released [SSDTBI for VS2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=42313) and was wondering if this only works with SQL Server 2014. Would I be able to edit the same SSIS packages that I have created in VS2012 and still have them work in SQL Server 2012?

Update: Judging by [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/analysisservices/archive/2014/04/02/sql-server-data-tools-business-intelligence-for-visual-studio-2013-ssdt-bi.aspx) it seems there are still issues with SSIS for SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 2):

As the blog post you're referring to specifies, SSDTBI for VS2013 only supports SSIS 2014 and cannot be used to edit SSIS packages for SQL Server 2012.
When trying to open an SSIS 2012 project, VS2013 will automatically try to upgrade your packages to make them compatible with SSIS 2014, thus making them incompatible with SSIS 2012.

One major bug in SSDTBI for VS2012 (the shaking components/jitter bug) can be fixed using the workarounds specified in the Connect article here: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/790470/when-dragging-ssis-objects-on-canvas-the-objects-shake-jiggle-jitter